# how to show the values in label which is in array index in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, for-loop

I have array with two items i want that if i=0 then it may show Ali and 1 then Jawaad but i do not want it static i want dynamic if there are 100 items in array so they must be given according to their index to label i am using loop but this loop always sets Jawaad to label.

```
NSArray*myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ali",@"Jawaad",nil];
int countTest=[myArray count];
NSLog(@"count Test is %d",countTest);

for (int i=0; i<countTest; i++) {

    DescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,20,206,84)];
    DescriptionLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentLeft;
    DescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    DescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    DescriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    NSString*testting=[myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    DescriptionLabel.text=testting;
    DescriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

    [scrollView addSubview:DescriptionLabel];
}
```

Comment: you are adding UIlabel in same position set different frame to add in scrollview.i.e you are adding UILabel 2 above UILable 1.

Comment: so UILabel2 is visible whereas UILabel1 not

Comment: change in x or y position of label in  **DescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,20,206,84)];** this line...

Comment: your all labels are add at (50,20,206,84) position. so, the last is visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels are overlapping. Try

```
int y = 20;
for (int i=0; i<countTest; i++) {

    DescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,y,206,84)];
y = y+ 84;
    DescriptionLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentLeft;
    DescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    DescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    DescriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    NSString*testting=[myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    DescriptionLabel.text=testting;
    DescriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

    [scrollView addSubview:DescriptionLabel];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
DescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,20,206,84)];
```

To :

```
DescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*206,20,206,84)];
```

Add :

```
[scrollView addSubview:DescriptionLabel];
[DescriptionLabel release];
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will overlap `UILabel` one upon one continuously because their `frames` are same.
You should increase y of the frame dynamically.

```
int y = 10;
for (int i=0; i<countTest; i++) {

    DescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,y,206,84)];
    DescriptionLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentLeft;
    DescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    DescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    DescriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    NSString*testting=[myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    DescriptionLabel.text=testting;
    DescriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

    [scrollView addSubview:DescriptionLabel];

    y = y+30
}
```